# Elegant way of computing information across 2 dataframes without for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for a more elegant way of doing this that doesn't use a for loop.
I have 2 dataframes, df1 and df2 with this format:
df1:

```
Position   Sample   Time  Measurement Type   Measurement  Unique_ID    
 1           1       1       A                   6.8        ID_1            
 1           1       2       A                   7.2        ID_1            
 1           1       3       A                   7.8        ID_1            
 1           1       4       A                   9.2        ID_1            
 2           2       1       A                   7.3        ID_2            
 2           2       2       A                   8.5        ID_2            
 2           2       3       A                   9.3        ID_2            
 2           2       4       A                   9.5        ID_2            
 3           1       1       B                   6.2        ID_3    
 3           1       2       B                   7.0        ID_3    
 3           1       3       B                   8.2        ID_3    
 3           1       4       B                   8.0        ID_3
```

df2:

```
Position   Sample     Unique_ID    Threshold 
 1           1         ID_1            8.3
 2           2         ID_2            8.9
 3           1         ID_3            7.1
```

I want to check for every row in df2 whether the measurement column crosses the threshold, and if it does I want to calculate the "Time value" at which the measurement would cross the threshold if we assume a straight line between measurements, and add this value to new column, 'Cross threshold'

```
for unique_ID in df2['Unique_ID']:
        y_last = 0
        threshold = float(df2.loc[df2['Unique_ID'] == unique_ID, 'Threshold'].tolist()[0])
        for x, y in zip(df1['Time'].tolist(), df1['Measurement'].tolist()):
            if y > threshold:
                val = (threshold - y_last)/(y-y_last) + x - 1 # straight line formula
                break
            else:
                y_last = y
                val = np.nan

        df2.loc[df2['Unique_ID'] == unique_ID, 'Cross_threshold'] = val
```

Result:

```
   Position  Sample Unique_ID  Threshold    Cross_threshold
        1       1      ID_1        8.3         3.357143
        2       2      ID_2        8.9         3.785714
        3       1      ID_3        7.1         1.750000
```

I would also like to check whether the measurements cross the threshold more than once, for example go above it at Time 2 and below it at Time 4. In the real case there will be many more measurements for each unique_ID and if there is more than one crossing of the threshold they need to be considered differently, add new column 'Doublecross_plus' = True or False

Thanks!

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: Editted with the output

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler and faster to combine the thresholds in df2 with df1 and calculate them?

Comment: I'm not sure how you mean, I can easily add the thresholds to df1, but what is your proposed way of calculating the crossing in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach.  I included some auxiliary values, for validation.  I created `df1` and `df2` using the values above.

```
# pull the threshold into df1
thresh = df2[['Unique_ID', 'Threshold']].set_index('Unique_ID').squeeze()
df1['thresh'] = df1['Unique_ID'].map(thresh)

# pull previous values onto current row
df1['time_prev'] = df1['Time'].shift(1)
df1['meas_prev'] = df1['Measurement'].shift(1)
df1['id_prev'] = df1['Unique_ID'].shift(1)

# compare current and previous measurements versus threshold...
df1['over_curr'] = df1['Measurement']          > df1['thresh']
df1['over_prev'] = df1['Measurement'].shift(1) > df1['thresh']

# ... and see if we crossed the threshold (^ is XOR) for current ID
df1['cross'] = ((df1['over_curr'] ^ df1['over_prev']) & 
                (df1['Unique_ID'] == df1['id_prev']))

# interpolate; must filter because this is meaningful when 'cross' is True
df1['Cross_threshold'] = (
    (df1['thresh'] - df1['meas_prev']) / (df1['Measurement'] - df1['meas_prev'])
    * (df1['Time'] - df1['time_prev'])
    + df1['time_prev']
)
```

Now filter and print.  I transposed the results, to avoid wrapping:

```
fields = ['Position', 'Sample', 'Unique_ID', 
          'Measurement', 'thresh', 'meas_prev', 
          'time_prev', 'Cross_threshold', 'Time']

mask = df1['cross']

# filter and export selected fields
print(df1.loc[mask, fields].transpose())

                      3     6        10
Position               1     2        3
Sample                 1     2        1
Unique_ID           ID_1  ID_2     ID_3
Measurement          9.2   9.3      8.2
thresh               8.3   8.9      7.1
meas_prev            7.8   8.5        7
time_prev              3     2        2
Cross_threshold  3.35714   2.5  2.08333
Time                   4     3        3
```

My 'cross threshold' values are different than the expected results in the original post.  For validation, I showed that:

- threshold is between current and previous measurement; and
- Cross_threshold time is between current and previous Time.

Comment: I don't really understand why your values are not the same